# akka-http unmarshalling works with string but doesn't work with entity

Tags: akka, akka-http, spray-json

I have an actor receiving two types of responses, both in json format: `Token` and `ShowInfoResponse`.

```
case class Token(token: String)
case class GetShowInfoResponse(data: List[TvdbEpisode])
case class TvdbEpisode(episodeName: String, airedSeason: Int, airedEpisodeNumber: Int, firstAired: String)
```

akka-http has no problems with unmarshalling entity with `Token`, but for some reason it won't unmarshal entity with `ShowInfoResponse` even though it works fine if you extract entity's body:

```
def receive = {
  case HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, _, entity, _) =>
    entity.dataBytes.runFold(ByteString(""))(_ ++ _).foreach { body =>
      Unmarshal(body.utf8String).to[ShowInfoResponse] pipeTo self
      Unmarshal(body.utf8String).to[Token] pipeTo self
    }
    Unmarshal(entity).to[ShowInfoResponse] pipeTo self
    Unmarshal(entity).to[Token] pipeTo self
  case Token(_) => 
    println("Received token")
  case ShowInfoResponse(_) =>
    println("Received show info")
```

Results in (notice lack of second 'Received show info'):

```
Received token
Received token
Received show info
```

Why does that happen?